# Verify that a function $f_A$ is an isometry

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm new to linear algebra, and I'm struggling with a simple question: I know that $f\in Hom(V,W)$ is an isometry if the Column space of an orthonormal basis of $V$ is an orthonormal basis of $W$. If we suppose that the matrix associated to the function $f$ is $$f_A=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}$$ How do we know that the function is an isometry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix is of the form
$$\pmatrix{
 \cos(\theta)& -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \\},$$ 
for $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$, and hence a proper rotation, i.e., in $SO_2(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Thank you. Based only on the definition I gave before, can we deduce that the function is an isometry?

Comment: Yes, the matrix is orthogonal with determinant $1$, i.e., in $SO_2(\Bbb R)$. This is what you have asked for - orthonormal... Here we have $V=W=\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: How is the function related to the basis of $V$ and $W$? I'm new to linear algebra.

Comment: The linear map from $\Bbb R^2\rightarrow \Bbb R^2$ is given by $x\mapsto f_Ax$. The columns of the matrix are the images of the basis elements $e_1,e_2$ under $f_A$.

Answer (score 0):

- $\det f_A = 1$
- $f_A f_A^T= I_2$.